# Getting daily results in a monthly format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I run a daily report that returns a list of equipment wasn't used on the previous shift. I need to find a way to run a report at the end of the month that does that for each day of the month and then list them in a table.

```
| REGO      | Fleet Number  | Branch    |
| 14        | 14            | MELB      |
| 18        | 18            | SYD       |
```

```
SELECT
  t."REGO" AS "REGO",
  t."FleetNumber" as "Fleet Number",
  b."Name" AS "Branch"
FROM "Truck" t
JOIN "Branch" b ON b."Id" = t."BranchId"
WHERE t."SubcontractorId" IS NULL 
  AND t."IsActive" IS TRUE
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "JobLeg" jl
    WHERE jl."TruckId" = t."Id"
      AND (
         (b."Id" = 'b2d5e35e-ce26-66d8-cb9f-42d1c92ad3f6' and 
        extract(HOUR from jl."EndDate" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AEST' ) >= '4' 
        and extract(HOUR from jl."EndDate"AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AEST' ) <  '15'
        and extract(MONTH from jl."EndDate"AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AEST' ) = '9')
        OR
        ((b."Id" = 'c9d2a7f8-59c8-5326-ae0f-706c032501c7' or b."Id" = '4e393240-ca96-3480-62b3-42cdc1a7ee22') 
        and extract(HOUR from jl."EndDate" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AEDT' ) >= '4' 
        and extract(HOUR from jl."EndDate"AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AEDT' ) <  '15'
        and extract(MONTH from jl."EndDate"AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AEDT' ) = '9')
        OR
        (b."Id" = 'eedefb97-c674-4a48-87a3-acf70027cd61' and
         extract(HOUR from jl."EndDate" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AWST' ) >= '4' 
        and extract(HOUR from jl."EndDate"AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AWST' ) <  '15'
        and extract(MONTH from jl."EndDate"AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'AWST' ) = '9'))
  )
```

I have updated the time to work on extracted hours and tried extracting the month from jl."EndDate" but that only returns results form REGO not used for the entire month, where I would like to find a way of doing to to return results for each day of the month and then pull them all together, hopefully with out having a sub query for each day of the month